# how to avoid cross join?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, mysql

I want to update/replace table data using batch file. And i store old_data in old.txt file and new_data in new.txt file.

```
old.txt:
101
India

new.txt:
1001
0891
```

and here is my batch script: demo.bat

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in (old.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%b in (new.txt) do (

mysql -u root -p tiger -host localhost -database empsrc -e "update table_name set col_name='%%b' where col_name='%%a'"

)
)
pause
```

when i execute the above batch file

```
101 is replaced with 1001 and 
india is also replaced with 1001
```

But,my Expected Output is

```
101 is replaced  with 1001
India should be replaced with 0891
```

how can i solve this problem ? can someone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FOR commands will execute one inside the other, creating the combinations of:

```
101, 1001
India, 1001
101, 0891
India, 0891
```

You would like one loop that reads in one entry from each file, then
execute the code.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14523100/165358),
here is a script that will echo the strings in pairs:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Rem First file is read with FOR /F command
Rem Second file is read via standard handle 3
3< old.txt (for /F "delims=" %%a in (new.txt) do (
  Rem Read next line from file2.txt
  set /P line2=<&3
  Rem Echo lines of both files
  echo %%a,!line2!
))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: one more doubt sir what if i want to skip 1st line in old .txt file..how can i place skip for old.txt file ..what i mean is for new.txt file we  are using for loop like (for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (new.txt) do ( ..